# 'Unitary' charts on odd-dimensional spheres

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry

Consider the odd-dimensional sphere $S^{2n+1} \subset \mathbb{C}^{n+1}$. One may talk variously about its structure as a contact, CR or Einstein-Sasaki manifold, but I'm looking for some specific down-to-earth detail that is hard to track down, namely charts that are complements of points and which are 'unitary' in the following sense.

The tangent space to $S^{n+1}$ at a point $x$ has a subspace isomorphic to the hermitian complement to the complex span of $x$. These patch together to give a complex vector bundle on the sphere -- and I'm fairly sure this is the holomorphic tangent bundle $HS^{2n+1}$ in the CR setting. Taking for $U$ the standard complement of the south pole, there is an isomorphism (even a CR isomorphism!) $\phi\colon Heis_n\simeq  U$, where $Heis_n$ is the Heisenberg group, diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^n\times\mathbb{R}$. Hence we can consider the induced isomorphism $H\, Heis_n \to HU$ and ask whether it is unitary with respect to the standard hermitian structure on the left, and the one induced from $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ on the right. This is all controlled by the isomorphism $\phi$, and if I'm not mistaken in my calculations, taking standard stereographic projection rewritten in complex coordinates doesn't do the trick (which is, making the relevant adjustments, only orthogonal).

> What's an explicit chart for an odd-dimensional sphere (considered as embedded in $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$) satisfying the above condition?

Asking for such a chart (and analogously over the complement of the north pole) is equivalent to giving a local section of $SU(n+1) \to S^{2n+1}$ over $U$ (and $V$). Note that from a Riemannian point of view I want to consider the sphere with the homogeneous metric from the isomorphism $S^{2n+1} \simeq SU(n+1)/SU(n)$.

I have a hard time believing no one has written this down before.

Comment: Notice that I really do want $U$, and not some other smaller open subspace!

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by a 'CR isomorphism'.  There is *no* diffeomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{C}^n\times\mathbb{R}\to U$ such that the differential of $\phi$ is complex linear on the tangent vectors to the complex hypersurfaces $\mathbb{C}^n\times\{x\}$, which is what I would think is meant by 'CR isomorphism' in this case.  (If such a $\phi$ existed, then $\phi\bigl(\mathbb{C}^n\times\{x\}\bigr)\subset U\subset S^{2n+1}$ would be a complex submanifold of $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$, which, by the maximum principle, is impossible.)

Comment: Just as Robert Bryant, I am puzzled by your assertion that $\mathbb{C}^n\times \mathbb{R}$ be CR-isomorphic to any open set of the sphere: to phrase Robert's objection differently, they live in opposite parts of the CR world, the former being Levy-flat and the later being strictly pseudoconvex. The relevant keyword is probably "Heisenberg group": in one of its guises, it is a pseudo-Riemannian manifold that parametrizes any complement of a point in the unit sphere of $\mathbb{C}^n$, and it can certainly be endowed with a natural CR-structure.

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner Yes, I meant $\mathbb{C}^n\times \mathbb{R}$ in its guise as the Heisenberg group (I'm afraid I'm used to thinking of diffeomorphisms, not worrying about metric or complex structures). I'm not entirely sure that particular chart is going to help, which is why I'm asking here.

Comment: @RobertBryant my fault: I didn't mean $\mathbb{C}^n\times\mathbb{R}$ with its usual CR manifold structure, see my comment to Benoît.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Part I:  The original question:**

Now that the question has been clarified, I can answer it.  The answer is 'no', there is no CR-isomorphism $\phi: \mathrm{Heis}\to U$ that is unitary on the holomorphic tangent bundles.

To see this, it's probably better to look at the dual $1$-forms.  Let $\alpha:T S^{2n+1}\to\mathbb{R}$ be the (unique) $1$-form whose kernel is the holomorphic tangent bundle $HS^{2n{+}1}\subset TS^{2n+1}$ and such that the $2$-form $\mathrm{d}\alpha$ restricts to $HS^{2n{+}1}$ to be a positive $(1,1)$-form that defines the Hermitian structure on $HS^{2n{+}1}$.  Similarly, let $\beta: T \mathrm{Heis}^{2n+1}\to\mathbb{R}$ be the (unique) $1$-form whose kernel is the holomorphic tangent bundle $H\mathrm{Heis}^{2n+1}\subset T\mathrm{Heis}^{2n+1}$ and such that the $2$-form $\mathrm{d}\beta$ restricts to $H\mathrm{Heis}^{2n+1}$ to be a positive $(1,1)$-form that defines the Hermitian structure on $H\mathrm{Heis}^{2n+1}$.

If $\phi:\mathrm{Heis}\to U$ were a CR-isomorphism that was unitary on the corresponding holomorphic tangent bundles, one would necessarily have $\phi^*\alpha = \beta$.  However, because the integral of $\alpha\wedge(\mathrm{d}\alpha)^n$ over $S^{2n+1}$ is finite, its integral over $U$ is also finite.  On the other hand, the integral of $\beta\wedge(\mathrm{d}\beta)^n$ over $\mathrm{Heis}$ is infinite because it is the integral of a left-invariant volume form over a noncompact Lie group.  Thus, $\phi$ cannot exist.

By the way, it would not be hard to show, using the method of equivalence, that the inequivalence holds even locally, i.e., there is no open subset of $\mathrm{Heis}^{2n+1}$ that is unitarily CR-diffeomorphic to any open subset of $S^{2n+1}$.  However, that would take a little more argument, and I am not sure that the OP would be interested.

**Part II:  The modified question:**

Now that the OP has clarified (in the comments below) what is meant by 'comes from' and that it is not actually required that the CR-isomorphism be literally unitary, it's easy to see how to establish the desired CR-isomorphism:

First, it helps to realize the $(2n{+}1)$-sphere as a hypersurface in $\mathbb{CP}^{n+1}$ as the hypersurface 
$$
|X_0|^2 = |X_1|^2 + \cdots +  |X_{n+1}|^2,
$$ 
by introducing homogeneous coordinates such that $z_i = X_i/X_0$.
Now one sees that the group $\mathrm{SU}(1,n{+}1)\subset \mathrm{SL}(n{+}2,\mathbb{C})$ acts transitively on this hypersurface (and preserves the CR-structure, of course).  If you now 'de-projectivize' this by looking at the part of the hypersurface that lies in the in affine chart that is a complement to the hyperplane $X_0-X_{n+1}=0$, one sees that this puts all of the $(2n{+}1)$-sphere except the point $[1,0,0,\ldots,0,1]$ (the 'north pole', if you will) in this affine chart, which is a copy of $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$.  To see this explicitly, make the coordinate change $X_0 = (Y+W)/2$, $X_{n+1}=(Y-W)/2$, leaving the others fixed, so that the equation for the hypersurface becomes
$$
\tfrac12(Y\overline{W}+W\overline{Y}) = |X_1|^2 + \cdots +  |X_n|^2,
$$
and now, on the complement of the hyperplane $W=0$, consider the affine coordinates
$$
u = \frac{Y}{W} = \frac{1+z_{n+1}}{1-z_{n+1}} \qquad\text{and}\qquad 
v_i = \frac{X_i}{W} = \frac{z_i}{1-z_{n+1}} \qquad 1\le i\le n, 
$$
Then the equation for the real hypersurface in these coordinates $(u,v_1,\ldots,v_n)$ on $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ is
$$
\mathrm{Re}(u) = |v_1|^2 + \cdots + |v_n|^2.
$$

This makes it easy to recognize as the Heisenberg model, and the formulae for $u,v_i$ in terms of the $z_i$ give the desired mapping.

In fact, the induced CR-isomorphism between the sphere minus a point and the Heisenberg group is 'conformally unitary' since all CR-isomorphisms between strictly pseudoconvex hypersurfaces are conformally unitary in the sense that the induced isomorphism between the corresponding holomorphic tangent spaces is always unitary up to a scalar multiple.

Comment: Hmm, not really the answer I wanted to hear, since that rules out the CR chart I was looking at (but at least it stops me from wrestling with futile calculations). My main question still stands, namely: what is _some_ chart that is unitary in the way described in the post?

Comment: @DavidRoberts:  I'm mystified by your comment above, since I don't really know where this 'chart' is supposed to take $U$.  Also, your final comment in the question, about the chart being equivalent to finding a section of the bundle $\mathrm{SU}(n{+}1)\to S^{2n+1}$ over $U$, doesn't make sense to me either.  Such a section, aka a local frame field along $U$, certainly does exist, but it's not going to be the framing associated to any coordinate chart.

Comment: (You know the following well, I imagine, but let me write it out for my own clarity of thinking) One can think of points in $S^{2n+1}\subset \mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ as the last column of a matrix in $SU(n+1)$, and an appropriate basis of $HS^{2n+1}$, considered as vectors in the ambient $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$, supplies the other $n$ columns. Ideally this basis comes from a complex analogue of a conformal map that supplies a chart, as happens when thinking of the round sphere and local sections of $O(n+1) \to S^n$. Is there any particular obstruction to getting such a frame field from a coordinate chart?

Comment: @DavidRoberts:  I think that what may be missing is clarification of the ill-defined 'comes from' in the above statement.  When considering, say, the inverse of stereographic projection $\sigma$, which is a conformal diffeomorphism from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to the complement of a point in $S^n$, one finds an orthonormal tangent frame field by letting $e_i$ be $\sigma'(\partial/\partial x^i)$ *after it has been normalized to have unit length*.  But you seem to be trying to get a CR-unitary frame field directly from a chart, without normalizing, and this is not possible.

Comment: Ah, my apologies for being vague! "comes from" was meant to be a bit more general than my original question about unitarity, which as you say is false. Rescaling is perfectly ok, if necessary! In fact I expected some rescaling, since that's what I found in the conformal case... Thanks for your patience in dragging this out of me :-)

Comment: Thanks for the expansion of part II! This is the part I needed: "the induced isomorphism between the corresponding holomorphic tangent spaces is always unitary up to a scalar multiple."